# Actionscript 3 call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3

is it possible to call javascript functions inside flash (as3)? How about not in the same domain? Can you provide an example snippet for samedomain and not same domain?

thanks!

Comment: You mean call javascript functions from flash? I think you should clarify the question, perhaps provide an example or scenario.

Comment: There are about ten other questions on the same topic.  Try using google or the search field in the top right corner of this page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the ExternalInterface you can communicate with JavaScript from Flash, however only in the window where the Flash application is running.

It is as easy as doing:

```
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunctionName", argument, argument, ...);
```

To do the reverse (calling Flash from JavaScript) you do the following first:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("jsFunctionName", callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction(arg:String):void {
    trace(arg);
}
```

And then you can call `jsFunctionName("foo")` from JavaScript.

See the [adobe docs](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html) for more info on that.

As for your cross domain, you can't as far as I know, but you may be able to proxy the call via your server.

Comment: can we also use to execute some random javascript passed as a string argument to the function ?

Comment: No as far as I know it just takes a global function name and calls that.