# Call an javascript function from actionscript script

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I am trying to build a button that will active specific Javascript function.

I tried:

```
getURL("javascript:functionName()");
```

but its seems like a bad idea (plus it doesn't work)..

or

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function call_javascript(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("functioName()");
}
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, call_javascript);
```

none of this working for me..

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you add the JavaScript function to your HTML?

Comment: Is the typo in your example ("functioName()") also in your code?

Comment: I'm just skimming this, but are you aware that you're trying to call 'functioName' as opposed to 'functionName' in your handler?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a duplicate. The question has been asked about 10 times before. But, here is an answer for you: `ExternalInterface.call("jsFunctionName", argument, argument, ...);`. It is very possible. [Click here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680962/actionscript-3-call-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling it wrong. The 1st param should be the function name without the brackets: `ExternalInterface.call("funcionName");`

Also note that you will have to have allowScriptAccess set to a value that will actually allow you to call the function (in your example you have sameDomain, which is OK).

Comment: I tested the code without the "()" in the .call but still. plus change the allowScriptAccess to always but noting.. http://jsfiddle.net/g9kYL/1/  (this is not going to work - just to show u the code)